# Active Admin and the Apartment Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, apartment-gem

I am new to Active Admin but from what I have seen so far I think this is quite easy to implement.

I have an app with the apartment gem to add multi-tenancy.

I am adding active admin to my app.  Apartment uses PostgreSQL schemas to segregate data.  So for example by default your models in Apartment have a 'public' tenant unless you call something like `Apartment::Tenant.switch!('abc')`.

In my app my `User` and `Company` model are in the public tenant and everything else is in tenants.  So out of the box Active Admin works fine except that the tenant models show no records - as they should.

I did some tinkering and manually added `Apartment::Tenant.switch!('abc')` one of my AA model files and that worked perfect.  Here is an ideal solution:

- when the `AdminUser` logs in the tenant gets set to a default (say the first tenant)
- On each tenanted model there could be a select menu that submits a param (?tenant=abc) and then the tenant is changed
- The active tenant is persisted in perhaps the `AdminUser` session store so you can work in the same tenant data until you need to switch.

I think I can do this myself quite easily but I wanted to see if there was any Active Admin specific issues I would need to address like:

- Does AA have an equivalent of a application controller?  It would be nice to keep the tenant switching logic in there vs the main one.
- The alternate AA Devise `AdminUser` has a separate session variable store available right?

Any suggestions would be appreciated - I will post my final solution / code back to this post once I sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

> Does AA have an equivalent of a application controller? It would be nice to keep the tenant switching logic in there vs the main one.

Indeed, there is an ActiveAdmin::BaseController, but the gem authors don't talk about using it for customization, not sure why. Seems like a fine place for the logic you're talking about.

I've never needed to modify it before, but [here's a blog article from someone who did](https://viget.com/extend/8-insanely-useful-activeadmin-customizations).

> The alternate AA Devise AdminUser has a separate session variable store available right?

Hmmm. Devise uses Warden for session management, which supports [multiple user 'scopes' logged in simultaneously](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Scopes) as well as [separate session data](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Authenticated-session-data), and if memory serves from when I've dug around in the code Warden puts the separate session data in a different key in the same cookie. Not sure if this is what you meant, but I verified that it definitely does not use a different cookie for users vs admins in my current ActiveAdmin-using Rails project.

Not a definitive answer, but moving the ball!

Comment: I think that answers both of my questions - when I try this out I will come back to update etc.  Thanks!

Comment: I have seemed to take a step backwards: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378248/switching-apartment-tenants-in-active-admin

Comment: I tried the ActiveAdmin::BaseController but it's doesn't seem to work.  I get the impression that the Active Admin module can't access the Apartment methods.  This is a bit over my head to resolve so far.