# Switching Apartment tenants in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, pundit, apartment-gem

This is an extension of my previous post:

[Active Admin and the Apartment Gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665234/active-admin-and-the-apartment-gem)

I thought I had this working but I am stuck.  I have a `Company` model in the public schema as the tenant model and `Locations` in individual tenants.  Here is my Active Admin `location.rb` file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Location do

#Apartment::Tenant.switch!('abc')

controller do

  #Apartment::Tenant.switch!('abc')

  before_filter do

    Apartment::Tenant.switch!('abc')

    skip_authorization
    skip_policy_scope

  end

end

end
```

The skip_authorization skip_policy_scope are from some Pundit issues I still have with AA.  As you can see I tried adding the `Apartment::Tenant.switch` in a few places.  Inside the controller block is the only place I can get it to work.

When I load the `Locations` index page it works fine and I see my tenant locations. The issue is that if I go back to the Dashboard or an other page and go back to Locations and call `Apartment::Tenant.switch` I get kicked back to the AA login screen and I can't log back in.  I have to manually enter the AA logout path to force an logout.

It's very weird and not sure how else to trouble shoot this.  The logs don't show much.

I was going to ad some logic here with a menu drop down to set a session variable etc. and then have the resource pages call `Apartment::Tenant.switch` when required but this is a show stopper as of now.  No idea if it's Devise, Pundit, Apartment, Active Admin or a combination.

**UPDATE**

Some progress - tried to add the output of the switch! call to a logger debug and that 'solved' the issue.  If I set the switch call to a variable it also goes away:

```
logger.debug "Apartment Switch: #{Apartment::Tenant.switch!('abc').inspect}"    
new_tenant = Apartment::Tenant.switch!('abc')
```

**UPDATE 2**

My previous update was erroneous - the issue remains.  I have narrowed it down to Devise.  The second `switch!` call never gets called as Devise throws a 401 error and kicks you out first.  I disabled Devise for Active Admin and my switching system works fine.  I can use a simple Company dropdown and sessions to switch the tenants on the fly.  Devise somehow does not like this at all.

Here is a Gist of my AA files: https://gist.github.com/jasper502/8fd16c31ee26667c5a16

Comment: It's not Pundit - I disabled it and I still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late, but have you tried storing the current tenant before switching to 'abc' on the before_filter, and then switching back to the previous tenant on an after_filter?

I haven't tried to reproduce anything, just a thought

Comment: I might try that. Right now I don't need auth as I have AA behind basic auth for now.